# Windows 10 Home Installation on Asus Z170 pro gaming motherboard

Tags: windows-10, installation, bios, hardware-failure, computer-building

I am having trouble installing Windows 10 Home edition 64bit on my new custom built PC. The motherboard is the Asus Z170 pro gaming. This is my second time building a PC an my first time building it completely by myself

The complete parts list is here https://pcpartpicker.com/list/Nxm6yf

Every time I insert the Windows 10 installation media and start the installation dialogue. I get to the step. *Preparing files for windows installation* (at about 80%) before the installation errors out and returns an error.

I have faced multiple errors/stop codes including.

- KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
- SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

among the ones that I recall. The weird part was that different error messages where being thrown each time the installation failed.

A family friend of ours who understands more than I do about computers tinkered some with the BIOS options and he managed to advance the installation a couple more percantage points and now I am now consistently getting the error  **0x80070570**

My friend seems to think that its is related to the security settings of the motherboard( something related to TPM).

I have tried booting both from a USB 3.0 drive shipped directly by Microsoft an USB 3.0 I made with the Windows Media creation tool and from a CD, which all now lead to the error code mentioned above

I am looking for a way to fix my installation so that I can install the OS and start using my PC.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you should try some tests using some Linux tools out there. If boards looks OK from there,  you should consider a faulty windows installer. Otherwise you should blame your motherboard.  You must consider that it could be also a faulty hard drive or ssd. Just test.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update [BIOS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-PRO-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/).

Otherwise it's a hardware problem.